# form validation problems with jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my first real project which involves form validation. I am experiancing a problem which I can not find the solution to.

The objective is this, there is a continue button which will be activated once all the field inputs have been passed as valid. I am going about this by creating seperate variables, all initially set as false, devoted to checking each input field. When the user has entered correct validation data, the variable is set to true.

I then run an if statement to check if all the variables are set to true, and if so, I activate the continue button which, when clicked, slides the next part of the form into the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <h3>Step 3: Your Details</h3>

    <!-- SLIDE-IN DIV TO REPRESENT DAY PASS -->

    <div class="row chosenmembership">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="yourdetails">

        <form action="" method="">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="form-control your-details">
                <span class="warning" id="email-warning"></span>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" class="form-control your-details">
                <span class="warning" id="name-warning"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" id="number" class="form-control your-details">
                <span class="warning" id="number-warning"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob" class="form-control your-details">
                <span class="warning" id="dob-warning"></span>
                </div>

                        </form>


                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="CONTINUE">



    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY:

```
//collection of input form fields//
    var formSubmit = $("#submit");
    var emailField = $("#email");
    var nameField = $("#name");
    var numberField = $("#number");

    //Switch to true when each validation has passed//
    emailValidated = false;
    nameValidated = false;
    numberValidated = false;

    //email validation check//
    emailField.on("input",function(){
        var emailInput = $(this).val()
        var testExp = new RegExp(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/);
        if (emailInput < 1) {
            $("#email-warning").html("Email is required!");
            $("#email-warning").css("visibility","visible");
            emailValidated = false;
        }

        else if (!testExp.test(emailInput)){
            $("#email-warning").html("Please enter a valid email");
            $("#email-warning").css("visibility","visible");
            emailValidated = false;

        }   else {
            $("#email-warning").css("visibility","hidden");
            emailValidated = true;
        }

        })

    //name validation check//
    nameField.on("input",function(){
        var nameInput = $(this).val()
        if (nameInput < 1) {
            $("#name-warning").html("Name is required");
            $("#name-warning").css("visibility","visible");
            nameValidated = false;
        } else {
            $("#name-warning").css("visibility","hidden");
            nameValidated = true;
        }

        })

    //contact number validation check//
    numberField.on("input",function(){
        var numberInput = $(this).val()

        if (typeof numberInput !== "number" && numberInput.length < 9) {
            $("#number-warning").html("Please enter a valid number");
            $("#number-warning").css("visibility","visible");
            numberValidated = false;
        } else {
            $("#number-warning").css("visibility","hidden");
            numberValidated = true;
        }

        })

    if (emailValidated && nameValidated && numberValidated){
        alert("correct");
        }


    })
```

at the moment, I am simply using the alert prompt to test if it is working, but it fails.

As mentioned, this is my first real form validation. Any other tips or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple things that I found from copying pasting your snippets of code. 1 there was an ending "})" without a beginning $(document).ready(function(){ ". 2 none of your ".on" statements had an ending semi colon.

Here is my javascript with a small change

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //collection of input form fields//
    var formSubmit = $("#submit");
    var emailField = $("#email");
    var nameField = $("#name");
    var numberField = $("#number");

    //Switch to true when each validation has passed//
    emailValidated = false;
    nameValidated = false;
    numberValidated = false;

    //email validation check//
    emailField.on("input", function () {
        var emailInput = $(this).val()
        var testExp = new RegExp(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/);
        if (emailInput < 1) {
            $("#email-warning").html("Email is required!");
            $("#email-warning").css("visibility", "visible");
            emailValidated = false;
        }

        else if (!testExp.test(emailInput)) {
            $("#email-warning").html("Please enter a valid email");
            $("#email-warning").css("visibility", "visible");
            emailValidated = false;

        } else {
            $("#email-warning").css("visibility", "hidden");
            emailValidated = true;
            enableContinue();
        }

    });

    //name validation check//
    nameField.on("input", function () {
        var nameInput = $(this).val()
        if (nameInput < 1) {
            $("#name-warning").html("Name is required");
            $("#name-warning").css("visibility", "visible");
            nameValidated = false;
        } else {
            $("#name-warning").css("visibility", "hidden");
            nameValidated = true;
            enableContinue();
        }

    });

    //contact number validation check//
    numberField.on("input", function () {
        var numberInput = $(this).val()

        if (typeof numberInput !== "number" && numberInput.length < 9) {
            $("#number-warning").html("Please enter a valid number");
            $("#number-warning").css("visibility", "visible");
            numberValidated = false;
        } else {
            $("#number-warning").css("visibility", "hidden");
            numberValidated = true;
            enableContinue();
        }

    });

    enableContinue = function () {
        if (emailValidated && nameValidated && numberValidated) {
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <h3>Step 3: Your Details</h3>

    <!-- SLIDE-IN DIV TO REPRESENT DAY PASS -->

    <div class="row chosenmembership">

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="yourdetails">

            <form action="" method="">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning" id="email-warning"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning" id="name-warning"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" id="number" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning" id="number-warning"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="dob" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning" id="dob-warning"></span>
                </div>

            </form>


            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" disabled="disabled" value="CONTINUE">



        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Your form CONTINUE button becomes enables once all fields have a value. Note: I did not try to improve your javascript any, just made it work.

Comment: Thanks so much John! I really appreciate it buddy. So was it just a case of typos? I really need to start learning how to write cleaner code.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

Right now you synchronically check validation variables at script, so they are all false. You have to asynchronically check them after form submit. Just add event listener to form submit to check variables like this:

```
document.getElementById('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(){
    if (emailValidated && nameValidated && numberValidated){
      alert("correct");
    }
});
```

Don't forget to set id to your form.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to save a lot of work if you leverage some of the built in HTML5 form validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

This simple example adds a new field every time you submit the form, as long as the existing fields are valid. You would need to test the state of the form to see if you should be adding another section or submitting.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $(this).find('fieldset').append('<input type="text" required />');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" required />
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="continue" />
</form>
```